# GGPlot Flip This Plot

Tags: r, ggplot2, heatmap

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)
HAVE = data.frame(VARS = c("cat", "dog", "fox", "rabbit"),
                  "a" = c(1,2,3,4),
                  "b" = c(2,3,1,4),
                  "c" = c(3,1,2,4))

HAVE1 = melt(HAVE, id.vars="VARS")

ggplot(HAVE1, aes(VARS, variable, fill= value)) + 
  geom_tile() +
  scale_fill_gradient(low="white", high="blue")
```

I wish to produce a color map from yellow (low value) to blue (high value). I wish for the columns on top to be the 'variable' and the yticks to be VARS such as: and please note it is just an example!!

[image]

---

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an approach with `pivot_longer` and `scale_x_discrete`. Note that `tidyr` is the successor to `reshape2`, but is by the same author.

We can re-order the factor levels of `VARS` to get them to plot in the order you want.

We can also get rid of the axis labels with `labs` and `element_blank`.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr)
HAVE %>% 
  pivot_longer(-VARS,names_to = "variable", values_to = "value") %>%
ggplot(aes(x = variable, y = factor(VARS, rev(levels(VARS))), fill= value)) + 
  geom_tile() +
  scale_fill_gradient(low="yellow", high="blue") +
  scale_x_discrete(position = "top") +
  labs(x = element_blank(), y = element_blank())
```

[image]

If you want the tiles to be square, just add the `coord_equal()` function:

```
ggplot(HAVE1,aes(x = variable, y = factor(VARS, rev(levels(VARS))), fill= value)) + 
  geom_tile() +
  scale_fill_gradient(low="yellow", high="blue") +
  scale_x_discrete(position = "top") +
  labs(x = element_blank(), y = element_blank()) + 
  coord_equal()
```

[image]

Comment: thanks so much yes this is great--I wonder can the rectangles be smaller boxes/squares ? I try to modify this but have not been able to

Comment: @bvowe if you edit your post with a paint image of what you had in mind, I can probably come up with something for you.

Comment: thanks so much I added a sample figure I found online with the difference being I would want the VARS on the left and the variables on top like you did

Comment: there are 40 VARS and 5 variables

Comment: I think adding `coord_equal()` should be what you're looking for.

Comment: that worked perfect thank you so much, and now I am embarrassed to say that the squares are so small I have not been able to figure out resizing them. I tried aes(width = 5, height = 5) but it did not really help..I think because there are so many variables

Comment: also I'm sorry but do you know how to reverse the value legend so it goes from low to high?

Comment: To reverse the legend, add `+ guides(fill = guide_colorbar(reverse = TRUE))`. The size of the image is controlled by Rstudio or in your call to `png` or `pdf`, not ggplot.

Comment: thank you so much that did the trick. I Guess for the size what I mean is that when I include my labels they are all overlapping because boxes are so small

Comment: If it's the x-axis labels, maybe try `+  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90))`?

Answer (score 4):

Here's an option with `coord_flip` to switch the axis and a reordering of the factor levels using `fct_rev`

```
ggplot(HAVE1, aes(x = fct_rev(as_factor(VARS)), variable, fill= value)) + 
  geom_tile() +
  scale_fill_gradient(low="yellow", high="blue") +
  coord_flip()
```

[image]